# Is it wise or acceptable to create a table with a different number of columns (td) for each row (tr)

Tags: html, html-table

I was wondering if it is wise or acceptable to create a table with a different number of columns (td) for each row (tr) using html. For example:

```
<table>

<tr>
<td>title</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>text</td>
<td>and more text</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Do I have to include the colspan?

Comment: "Wise" or "acceptable" are words as subjective as "ugly" is, and I'd say that ugliness will be a more determinant factor in this case.

Comment: Did you try it out and see what it looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to include a `colspan=`, however, the size of the largest `<td></td>` will determine the width of the column as it is displayed.  Different browsers (and releases) will render the table slightly differently (How the non-defined area is displayed).

Answer (score 0):

Not only is it **NOT** wise, it's nonconformant with HTML standards.
Use the `colspan` attribute.